# sql query to select id from table1 and update into table2

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables ok

```
  hawker_master table
  id   hawker_name
  1     raj
  2     vicky

  customer_entry table
  hawkername
   raj
   raj
   vicky
```

I need sql query which select id of particular hawker_name from hawkermaster and update id in place of hawkername in customer_entry table like below ex..

FOR EX -

```
  customer_entry table
  hawkername
   1
   1
   2
```

Comment: try to do yourself and ask if some error or problem is happening.

Comment: You should be able to do this with a sub query, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the multi-table `UPDATE` syntax to perform a join:

```sql
UPDATE customer_entry ce
  JOIN hawker_master  hm ON hm.hawker_name = ce.hawkername
SET    ce.hawkername = hm.id
```